# Can I use markdown syntax in r documentation so that they appear in my help files

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, documentation

I am writing/trying to write some `.Rd` help files in R for a self-created package which can be found in the following [Github link](https://github.com/Chitran1987/DataAnalyze1.0). Herein, I am trying to write the help files or `.Rd` files for the function `fit_2D`.
I used some basic tricks that I learnt while using R markdown, but unfortunately they don't seem to execute in the code for the `.Rd` help files.

Is there some way I can turn on Markdown syntax usage/recognition while using/coding into .Rd files?

My code is shown below

```r
\name{fit_2D}
\alias{fit_2D}
%- Also NEED an '\alias' for EACH other topic documented here.
\title{
Iteratively fits 2D regression models to a dataset using the function \code{fit_2D(func, dat, it, op_v)}
}
\description{
The function, \code{fit_2D}, takes four arguments, **func**, **dat**, **it**, **op_v** and fits the *2D* model described by the argument **func** into the data described by the argument **dat**. The parameter **it** describes the number of iterations that the code generates before it decides to declare that the starting/intial values of the vector to be iterated, **op_v**, is a bad starting point to search for a local minima within the given number of iterations, **it**. In such cases the message *solution did not converge* will be displayed. **op_v** is a vector comprising the initial values/guess point from where the vector will iterate itself to look for a local minima. It must however be remembered that the function, \code{fit_2D}, does not have pre-defined default values attached to its arguments and also that the function **does not** under present circumstances support optimization algorithms with *constraints* defined on them. This however is a work in progress and will be taken care of in future contexts.
}
\usage{
fit_2D(func, dat, it, op_v)
}
%- maybe also 'usage' for other objects documented here.
\arguments{
  \item{func}{
The argument \code{func} is a R function. It defines the model that the user wants to fit to his data defined in the argument \code{dat}. The argument has certain rules and restrictions.
1. The argument \code{func} has to be a user-defined function itself
2. The function that the user passes to the argument \code{func} must itself be a function that accepts only one argument. This argument must be the vector that needs to be iterated, \code{op_v}.
3. The vector \code{op_v} must be defined after the definition of the function that is to be passed in \code{func}, failing which, the argument passed in \code{func} ceases to be a function and this would throw an error. *See example below*
4. The function has to return a value, **y**. *See example below*
}
```

I expect the code to be able to parse **y** into boldface, but that does not happen. Also, I can't use code environments like I am using here. Is there some way to tell R-Studio to use markdown in my `.Rd` files? Or is there a separate syntax list for coding in `.Rd` files. I would prefer to integrate markdown parsing into my `.Rd` files, since it makes my life much easier, as I have some prior experience with that. I am very new to R and *especially* package creation, any help is of utmost appreciation at this point.

Comment: I'd really recommend you to use `roxygen2` to create your documentation files, but whether you're using roxygen or creating the .rd files directly, you can use `\emph{}` and `\strong{}` for italic and bold typefaces, respectively. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html

Answer (score 0):

No, Rd files have their own syntax which is closer to LaTeX than Markdown (but it's not LaTeX).  The syntax is documented in the Writing R Extensions manual which comes with R.  More technical details of the parser are documented in http://developer.r-project.org/parseRd.pdf.

There was a project a year or two ago to write a parser that would allow input in Markdown syntax; I don't know its status.

If you use Roxygen (putting help text in comments in .R files), I believe it can accept Markdown syntax if enabled.

Comment: I know latex and I know it better than I know markdown, it could be helpful. Do you have some documentation in mind towards which you could direct me?

Comment: [Roxygen](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/formatting.html) uses the same pseudo-LaTeX syntax as `.Rd` to format text. You can use markdown in Roxygen comments, but you have to explicitly enable it.